# LG Phoenix 3 stuck on firmware update

Tags: lg, lg-phoenix-2

My LG phoenix 3 is stuck on firmware update when it was being unlocked from the network and it is showing: "do not unplug until the process is complete".

What should i do?

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148733/lg-phone-seemingly-stuck-on-firmware-update